# How to change orthographic scale with the pixel resolution and vice versa?

Tags: camera

I have been using blender and while rendering I came into a problem, I change the camera size but not the resolution, this can be particularly tricky when the image needs to have the contents at the same size but the resolution be different. For example, 2D video game sprites are all the same size in appearance but differ in frame resolution. Such as games like Friday Night Funkin' where the sprites a in different sizes.[image: changing the orthographic scale but the resolution doesn't change]

As you can see the scale changes but not the resolution, are there any settings or plugins that could solve my issue? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you expect? The _Focal Length_ on a perspective camera can be used to zoom in and out, the _Ortographic Scale_ is the equivalent on an orthographic camera. Like real cameras, zooming in/out doesn't change the resolution of pictures you take - it changes how far or close the pictured object is. It's the same in Blender - why should the resolution change when you zoom in? If you want a different resolution but the object should stay framed as it is, do exactly that: change the resolution (under _Output Properties_ > _Format_ > _Resolution X_ & _Y_) or the _Percentage_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I was looking to see if it could change with it, I get what you're trying to say but i have a different problem where im trying to import these into a game

Comment: Yes, I understand you want different sprite sizes - well, you have to render different resolutions or create them from one resolution in an image editing software. Do you think game creators get different sprite resolutions by zooming the camera in and out?

Comment: of course not, I just want to make sure every animation is the same size with the camera scale being different

Comment: If you want every animation to be the same size, why do you change the camera scale at all? Or do you mean for different sized objects and then... what? They should be fit in scale to each other but still fill the complete image frame? If so, that's nowhere mentioned in the question. As it stands I don't see why you are not simply rendering in different solutions or scaling the rendered image in Photoshop, Gimp etc.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1075429196974792725/1090074025335717988/image.png

Comment: These too objects are in too different image resolutions but when put next to each other but when put next to each other they work perfectly in a game with a foreground.

Comment: I dont know if i need to be more clear with my examples but thats what i came up with

Comment: It seems I need to be more clear with what I'm saying. 1. You cannot animate resolution. An animation needs to have the same resolution from start to end. 2. Why do you need different resolutions? The objects can have the same size as in your image, no matter how much blank space is around them i.e. what resolution the image has. 3. I still don't see what determines this perfectly working together. In your linked example, the images have different resolutions, the objects, cube and cylinder have different height and width. Is it their original size? Then just leave the camera as it is.

Comment: I figured out a solution to my problem, ill render it larger for everything and just crop it after.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I already meant in my second comment, to create them from one resolution in an image editing software. Render everything in the same resolution and then edit the image to the size you want/need.

Comment: might take a while tho